# How can i use the actionCommand of a set of buttons to make selections after another using java?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm developing an ATM user interface, tying to make a set of buttons that represent constant values to be used to make another selection based on the outcome of the first selection. for instance, if one of the buttons, which value represents withdrawal in the main menu options, is clicked and a JPanel containing withdrawal amount options is presented, i want to be able to use the same set of buttons their respective values to make the  withdrawal amount selection. At the moment with the code i'm able to write the selection from the main menu just goes through to selecting withdrawal amount without allowing me to make the selection.

```
public class ATM implements ActionListener{

    private String[] command = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"};
    private static final int BALANCE_INQUIRY = 1;
    private static final int WITHDRAWAL = 5;
    private static final int DEPOSIT = 2;
    private static final int TRANSFER_FUND = 6;
    private static final int EXIT = 3;
    private int selection;
    Transaction currentTransaction = null;

    public ATM{
        choiceButtons = new JButton[8];
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            choiceButtons[i] = new JButton();
            choiceButtons[i].setActionCommand(command[i]);
            choiceButtons[i].setFocusable(false);
            choiceButtons[i].addActionListener(this);   
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        selection = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
    }

    private Transaction performTransactions(){
        boolean userExited  = false;
        while(!userExited){
            switch(selection){
                case BALANCE_INQUIRY:
                    currentTransaction = new BalanceInquiry();
                    currentTransaction.execute();
                case WITHDRAWAL:
                    currentTransaction = new Withdrawal();
                    currentTransaction.execute();
                case DEPOSIT:
                    currentTransaction = new Deposit();
                    currentTransaction.execute();
                case TRANSFER_FUND:
                    currentTransaction = new Transfer();
                    currentTransaction.execute();
                    break;
                case EXIT:
                    userExited = true;
                    break;
            }
        return currentTransaction;
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Withdrawal extends Transaction{    

private int[] amounts = {0, 10, 40, 20, 100, 60, 200};
private static final int OTHER = 7;
private static final int CANCELLED = 8;
private boolean menuOfAmountDisplayed;

public Withdrawal(){
}   

public void execute(){
    try{
        screen.updateScreen(displayMenuOfAmounts());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        menuOfAmountDisplayed = true;

        performWithdrawal();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){}
}

public void performWithdrawal(){
    boolean cashDispensed = false;
    BankDatabase bankDatabase = getBankDatabase();

    double availableBalance;
    int userChoice = 0;
    while(userChoice == 0){
        switch(selection){
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
                userChoice = amounts[selection];
                break;
            case OTHER:
                userChoice = OTHER;
                break;
            case CANCELLED:
                userChoice = CANCELLED;
                break;  
        }
    }
    return userChoice;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so if I understand correctly, the second set of input buttons should do nothing more then record the value that the user enters (lets say it's the amount), when the user clicks "okay" (or some other "continue" action), the amount value is either returned or passed back via some kind of observer pattern to the caller, which can then take appropriate action, withdrawing or depositing the amount request

Comment: Thanks for attending to my question. Yes, except that it's the same set of input buttons (8 buttons) with the same constant values of 1 to 8. if the user clicks button(5) withdrawal for example, the user should be able to click one this same set of buttons to make a choice withdrawal amount which value is then passed through to the account for appropriate action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer to the question is to use some kind observer pattern through which, you can be notified of different states of the key pad (accept/cancel).  This means that the key pad does a single job, deals with the user input and tells some other party that the user has chosen some course of action.

`ActionListener` is an obvious candidate for this, but you're going to have to write the logic to get it work (the registration and event triggering code)

This is an overly simplified idea of the concept.  It presents a menu to the user, when the user selects an option, it sets an appropriate state flag and shows the key pad.

When the key pad triggers an event, the `AtmPane` checks the current state and takes appropriate action based on that state.

This could be further expand, with dedicated withdraw and deposit classes used to mange the events, but I wanted to to present the basic idea

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import static javax.swing.Action.NAME;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DaddyATM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DaddyATM();
    }

    public DaddyATM() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new AtmPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class AtmPane extends JPanel {

        private KeyPadPane keyPadPane;
        private MenuPane menuPane;
        private CardLayout cardLayout;

        private MenuActions menuAction = null;

        public AtmPane() {
            setLayout((cardLayout = new CardLayout()));
            add((keyPadPane = new KeyPadPane()), "keypad");
            add((menuPane = new MenuPane()), "menu");

            menuPane.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
                    if (MenuActions.WITHDRAW.isEqualToCommand(cmd)) {
                        menuAction = MenuActions.WITHDRAW;
                        cardLayout.show(AtmPane.this, "keypad");
                    } else if (MenuActions.DEPOSIT.isEqualToCommand(cmd)) {
                        menuAction = MenuActions.DEPOSIT;
                        cardLayout.show(AtmPane.this, "keypad");
                    }
                }
            });

            keyPadPane.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
                    if (KeyPadActions.ENTER.isEqualToCommand(cmd)) {
                        double amount = keyPadPane.getValue();
                        switch (menuAction) {
                            case WITHDRAW:
                                System.out.println("You withdrew " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(amount));
                                break;
                            case DEPOSIT:
                                System.out.println("You deposited " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(amount));
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    cardLayout.show(AtmPane.this, "menu");
                    menuAction = null
                }
            });

            cardLayout.show(this, "menu");
        }

    }

    public enum MenuActions {
        WITHDRAW("withdraw"),
        DEPOSIT("deposit");

        private String command;

        private MenuActions(String command) {
            this.command = command;
        }

        public boolean isEqualToCommand(String cmd) {
            return command.equals(cmd);
        }

        public String getCommand() {
            return command;
        }
    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {

        public MenuPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            add(new JButton(new MenuAction("Withdraw", MenuActions.WITHDRAW)), gbc);
            add(new JButton(new MenuAction("Deposit", MenuActions.DEPOSIT)), gbc);
        }

        public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
            listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, listener);
        }

        public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
            listenerList.remove(ActionListener.class, listener);
        }

        protected void fireActionPerformed(MenuActions action) {
            ActionListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(ActionListener.class);
            ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, action.getCommand());
            for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.actionPerformed(evt);
            }
        }

        public class MenuAction extends AbstractAction {

            private MenuActions action;

            public MenuAction(String name, MenuActions action) {
                this.action = action;
                putValue(NAME, name);
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fireActionPerformed(action);
            }

        }

    }

    public enum KeyPadActions {
        ENTER("enter"),
        CANCELED("canceled");

        private String command;

        private KeyPadActions(String command) {
            this.command = command;
        }

        public boolean isEqualToCommand(String cmd) {
            return command.equals(cmd);
        }

        public String getCommand() {
            return command;
        }

    }

    public class KeyPadPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton[] numbers;
        private JButton cancel, clear, enter;
        private JFormattedTextField amountField;

        public KeyPadPane() {

            NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            amountField = new JFormattedTextField(currencyFormat);
            amountField.setColumns(10);
            amountField.setHorizontalAlignment(JFormattedTextField.RIGHT);
            amountField.setValue(0d);
            amountField.setEditable(false);

            numbers = new JButton[10];
            for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
                numbers[index] = new JButton(new NumberAction(index));
            }

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            add(amountField, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 4));

            List<Component> components = new ArrayList<>();
            components.add((cancel = new JButton(new CancelAction())));
            components.add((clear = new JButton(new ClearAction())));
            components.add((enter = new JButton(new EnterAction())));

            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                    buttons.add(numbers[(row * 3) + (col + 1)]);
                }
                buttons.add(components.get(row));
            }
            buttons.add(new JButton());
            buttons.add(numbers[0]);
            buttons.add(new JButton());
            buttons.add(new JButton());
            add(buttons);
        }

        public double getValue() {
            return (double) amountField.getValue();
        }

        public void append(int number) {
            Double objValue = (Double) amountField.getValue();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Double.toString(objValue));
            sb.insert(sb.indexOf("."), number);
            amountField.setValue(Double.parseDouble(sb.toString()));
        }

        public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
            listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, listener);
        }

        public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
            listenerList.remove(ActionListener.class, listener);
        }

        public void clear() {
            amountField.setValue(0d);
        }

        public void enter() {
            fireActionPerformed(KeyPadActions.ENTER);
            clear();
        }

        public void cancel() {
            fireActionPerformed(KeyPadActions.CANCELED);
            clear();
        }

        protected void fireActionPerformed(KeyPadActions action) {
            ActionListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(ActionListener.class);
            ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, action.getCommand());
            for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.actionPerformed(evt);
            }
        }

        public class ClearAction extends AbstractAction {

            public ClearAction() {
                putValue(NAME, "Clear");
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                clear();
            }

        }

        public class EnterAction extends AbstractAction {

            public EnterAction() {
                putValue(NAME, "Enter");
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                enter();
            }

        }

        public class CancelAction extends AbstractAction {

            public CancelAction() {
                putValue(NAME, "Cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cancel();
            }

        }

        public class NumberAction extends AbstractAction {

            private int number;

            public NumberAction(int number) {
                this.number = number;
                putValue(NAME, Integer.toString(number));
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                append(number);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is quite an interesting concept, i should have to study it and adapt it for my code. I am very grateful for the help.

Comment: There are a number of core OO design patterns which have been developed to solve common problems faced by developers on a daily bases, it makes it easier for people to understand the code, but also reduces the time and effort you need to put in to solve these problems.  Start by having a look at [Design Patterns](http://www.oodesign.com/) for starters.  The above is basic concept of an observer pattern

Comment: Thanks for the link. Great resource to help towards designing more logically. I'm reconsidering my design already. Thank you.